# Select branch in git dependency

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Its possible to select some branch in the `pubspec.yaml`?

```
  library_sdk:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/library/library.git
```

I need to use the develop branch instead master.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Ok, from flutter doc (https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies):

> If you want to depend on a specific commit, branch, or tag, add a ref
> argument:

```
 dependencies:   
     kittens:
       git:
         url: git://github.com/munificent/kittens.git
         ref: some-branch
```

> The ref can be anything that Git allows to identify a commit.